# Wrong eigenvalues for 2D QHO using DEigensystem[]

Tags: differential-equations, eigenvalues

I try to solve 2D Quantum Harmonic Oscillator using DEigensystem[] in Mathematica 13.0. Here is my code:

```
$Assumptions = {L \[Element] PositiveReals, \[HBar] \[Element] 
    PositiveReals, \[Omega] \[Element] PositiveReals, 
   m \[Element] PositiveReals} ;
\[ScriptCapitalH] = -\[HBar]^2/(2 m) Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] + 
   1/2 m \[Omega]^2 (x^2 + y^2) u[x, y];
\[ScriptCapitalB] = DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, True];
{vals, funs} = 
  DEigensystem[{\[ScriptCapitalH], \[ScriptCapitalB]}, 
   u[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] FullRegion[2], 8];
vals[[1]]
```

The result is:

```
(\[Omega] \[HBar])/2
```

It seems wrong, because the ground state energy for 2D QHO is:

```
\[Omega] \[HBar]
```

Do you have any idea what is wrong?

Comment: It looks like a bug. Try $\hbar=\omega=m=1$ and `NDEigensystem[{\[ScriptCapitalH], \[ScriptCapitalB]},  u[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] Rectangle[{-10, -10}, {10, 10}], 8]`. It gives `{1.00251, 2.00887, 2.00887, 3.01774, 3.03181, 3.03397, 4.03759, \
4.04747}`.